# logrotate not running when triggered by systemd OnBootSec

Tags: debian, systemd, logrotate

On a

Linux xxxxx 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

system I am trying to run logrotate only at system boot and not at any other schedule.

/etc/logrotate.conf contains:

```
weekly
rotate 99
create
dateext
dateformat .%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Using

> systemctl edit logrotate.timer

/etc/systemd/system/logrotate.timer.d/override.conf

contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=
Description=On boot rotation of log files

[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnBootSec=1us
AccuracySec=2us
```

Using

> systemctl edit logrotate.service

/etc/systemd/system/logrotate.service.d/override.conf

contains:

```
[Unit]
ConditionACPower=

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.conf
```

After boot and login, *systemctl status* shows logrotate.timer as loaded active elapsed and logrotate.service as loaded inactive dead. An actual logrotate did not take place at system startup. I see no error messages in any logfile. Anything else looks fine.

When I run

> logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.conf

manually, the log rotation is executed as expected. So, I assume no logrotate setup error.

Anybody here who has an idea what is going wrong and/or how to debug or fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To run logrotate only once per system boot, do the following:

Remove logrotate from any cron / anacron schedule.

Disable logrotate.timer:

> systemctl disable logrotate.timer

Override logrotate.service with

> systemctl edit logrotate.service

and enter the following content into override.conf:

```
[Unit]
ConditionACPower=
RequiresMountsFor=/var/log
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=syslog.service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.conf
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

This works on an otherwise virgin Debian system (without graphical desktop, i.e. a server).